# Plotly subplots - color legend for multicoloured subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am new to plotly and I am trying to create subplots and display color legend. My dataframe looks like this:

```
   A   B  C  D        State  
0  1   3  5  2      INITIAL    
1  2  10  5  1         DONE  
2  4   1  7  6  IN_PROGRESS  
3  4   3  2  8       PAUSED
```

This is what I need as end result:
[image: ![enter image description here]

But I cannot make it work. I tried using plotly.express and then constructing the result figure by adding the components generated by it. This is the code:

```py
fig = go.Figure()

figures = [
        df.plot.scatter(x="A", y="B", color="State"),
        df.plot.scatter(x="A", y="C", color="State")
    ]

fig = make_subplots(rows=len(figures), cols=1) 

for i, figure in enumerate(figures):
    for trace in range(len(figure["data"])):
        fig.append_trace(figure["data"][trace], row=i+1, col=1)

fig.update_xaxes(title_text="A", row=2, col=1)  
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="A", row=1, col=1)       
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="C", row=2, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="B", row=1, col=1)
fig.show()
```

This is the result:
[image]

Which is close to what I need besides States being repeated. Do you know how can I add the "State" header here and avoid repeated states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate legends use set to remove duplicates from the graph configuration information and update the initial legend.
Also, as complex customisation is not possible with express, it is easier and programmatically clearer to deal with this in the graph object. It is also possible to convert the data frame from horizontal to vertical format and loop through the same extraction conditions.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True) 

for i,g in enumerate(['B','C','D']):
    for k,(s,c) in enumerate(zip(df['State'].unique(),
                                 ['red','black','blue','green'])):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df.loc[k,'A']],
                                 y=[df.loc[k,g]],
                                 mode='markers',
                                 marker_color=c,
                                 legendgroup=s,
                                 name=s),
                      row=i+1, col=1)

# Remove duplicate legends
names = set()
fig.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace:
        trace.update(showlegend=False)
        if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))

fig.update_xaxes(title_text="A", row=3, col=1, tickvals=[1,2,3,4])  
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="D", row=3, col=1)       
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="C", row=2, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="B", row=1, col=1)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks exactly how I want it to look. One question: with this solution e.g. if I click on the INITIAL label on the right-hand side, it eliminates the points with state INITIAL only on the A vs. B subplot - is it possible to apply the filter to all subplots when I click on a certain state?

Comment: grouping can be used for all subplots. The legend looks a little different. It is my understanding that this is due to the ability to add a group title to go along with the grouping, which adds extra white space for this purpose.